# Visual studio online 'monaco' and bitbucket. Creating new branches?

Tags: bitbucket, visual-studio-monaco

I create a branch on visual studio online 'monaco' and my repository was cloned from bitbucket.

When I create a new branch in monaco and push to bitbucket, I can push and update all my master branch changes but my 'newBranch' does not get synced. It's like it exists somewhere else within 'monaco'.